# If s and t are positive step functions defined on an interval [a,b], is s/t also a step function?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions, continuity

I think it is, assuming that both functions are defined on the same partition (joint refinement), if we let s = $\sum_{i=1}^n c_i1_{[p_{i-1},p_i]}$ and t =$\sum_{i=1}^n d_i1_{[p_{i-1},p_i]}$ then $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{c_i}{d_i}1_{[p_{i-1},p_i]}$ is a step function,
provided $d_i$ $\neq$ 0. This is probably wrong though,any help would be appreciated

Comment: The idea of the proof looks good, but of course it still needs work to fully write everything out in proper mathematical language.

Comment: What are $s_i,t_i?$

Comment: You can not use the same $L[_{−1},–]$ with di and ci what are  si and ti ? but you can combine s and t if you overlay them

Comment: It is more comfortable for the proof to write $[p_{i-1},pi)$ everywhere, or $(p_{i-1},pi]$ everywhere, Then, the result becomes obvious (with $s_i=c_i$ and $t_i=d_i$).

Comment: Oops in the the last sum I meant ci/di not si/ti.

Comment: Why is it a problem for you ? What do you "fear" ?

Comment: I just thought maybe it wasn't rigorous enough.

Comment: If $\psi: \mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ is any function, then $\psi(s, t)$ is a step function.

Comment: Are you assuming that $\frac st$ exists? If not, then $\frac st$ need not be a step function on $[a.b]$, as it may not be well-defined everywhere on the interval.

Comment: Yes, I am assuming s/t exists.